# By using trapezoidal rule I got the answer $0.005$ but it is given $0.56$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

Integration by trapezoidal method of
$$\int_{1}^{3}\log_{10}(x)\,dx$$
using seven 
distinct values (equally covering the whole range) is _

Comment: _How_ do you get $0.005$? If you don't show your calculations, nobody will be able to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Dividing the interval from 1 to 3 with 7 values means dividing the interval into 6 subintervals each of length (3- 1)/6= 2/6= 1/3 so your values are 1, 4/3, 5/3, 2, 7/3, 8/3, 3.  The corresponding function values are log(1)= 0, log(4/3)= 0.125, log(5/3)= 0.222, log(2)= 0.301, log(7/3)= 0.368, log(8/3)= 0.426. log(3)= 0.477 (rounded to three decimal places).  The "trapezoid method" essentially uses the **average** of two consecutive values times $\delta x$.

Those averages are (0+ 0.125)/2= 0.062, (0.125+ 0.222)/2= 0.174, (0.222+ 0.301)/2= 0.262, (0.301+ 0.368)/2= 0.334, (0.368+ 0.426)/2= 0.397, (0.426+ 0.477)/2= 0.452.

The sum of those averages is 0.062+ 0.174+ 0.262+ 0.334+ 0.397+ 0.452= 1.681.  Finally multiply that by $\delta x= 1/3$, we 1.681/3= 0.561.  As Henning Makholm said, we cannot say what you might have done wrong because you have not shown what you did!